# Boolean Algebra Proof

Tags: boolean, algebra

I am teaching myself Boolean Algebra.

I was hoping someone could correct the following if I'm wrong.

Question:

Using Boolean Algebra prove that A(A+B)=A.

A(A+B) would mean A and ( A or B).

My Answer:

A(A+B) = A(A(1+B)) = A(A1) = AA = A.

Comment: This is just the absorption law btw.

Comment: I realise that but I have been asked to prove it's correct

Comment: Could you annotate the steps? I don't see what rule you used in the first step

Comment: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/258/notes/absorption-proofs.html so where's the problem?

Comment: I factorized the (A + B) to make it A (1 + B) but this is where I think ive gone wrong.

Comment: That doesn't look right, A(1+B) doesn't even depend on B, but A+B does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra / logic / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

Distribute A first, as such:

```
A(A+B)=A

AA+AB=A

A+AB=A

A(1+B)=A

A(1)=A

A=A
```

You seemed to skip a couple steps within your first step: you essentially stated A+B=1+B, which is not always correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to propositional logic. We use the notions below to denote *and*, *or*, and *logically equivalent* respectively:

[image]

Below is your equation rewritten to use this notion:

[image]

To complete the proof, 3 laws are applied. At line 2, the distributed law is applied for reduction, the idempotent law is applied at line 3, and the absorption law is applied at line 4:

[image]

And this completes the proof.